# Why did I get only one badge for this answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

> Great Answer: Answer voted up 100
>   times. This badge can be awarded
>   multiple times.

Yet [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/423837#423837) for which I was upvoted 207 times as of now, only gave me 1 golden badge for great answer? Why is that?

Comment: The system was angry that it already gave you one gold badge for it and refused to dole out another. Those gold badges are expensive.

Comment: @TheTXI: Plus, the system *hates* subjective questions.

Comment: The system is a self-loathing soul.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only get one per answer.

- You get a bronze "Nice Answer" badge at ten votes.
- You get a silver "Good Answer" badge at 25 votes.

Would you expect to receive 20 "Nice Answer" badges? Or even 8 "Good Answer" badges?

Answer (score 6):

you don't keep getting the same badge on the same question. You reached 100, you got the badge.

Answer (score 1):

You already got a "great answer" award for that answer.  Why should that answer become 2 great answer awards? haha, it's just logical.

Besides, didn't you already get "Nice Answer" and "Good Answer" before you got the "Great Answer"?  Do you need a Super Answer?

Comment: What's after Super Answer? Maybe with 1000 upvotes you can get the "Holy Crap, Is That Like The Best Answer EVAR Or What?" badge.